# pandas dataframe logical array referencing in .loc

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue with df.loc using logical indicators for the rows.  Here is a snip of code that summarizes the issue.  It appears the logical vector is confusing the .loc function

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame()
a['name'] = ['fred','bob','bob','jeff']
a['col_1'] = [1., 2., 3., 4.]
a['col_2'] = a['col_1'] + 4
a['col_3'] = a['col_1'] + 8
print(a)

# %%
b = pd.DataFrame()
b['name'] = ['bob','bob']
b['col_1'] = [2.1, 3.1]
b['col_2'] = b['col_1'] + 4
b['col_3'] = b['col_1'] + 8
print(b)

# %%
vars2change = ['col_2', 'col_3']
a.loc[a.name=='bob', vars2change] = b.loc[:,vars2change]

print('What am I missing?')
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `.loc` pays attention to the index of the boolean series you give to it:

```py
>>> a.name == 'bob'
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
```

and

```py
>>> b.loc[:,vars2change]
   col_2  col_3
0    6.1   10.1
1    7.1   11.1
```

Pandas will try to match the indices, and you end up filling only at the intersection where indices match and `a.name == 'bob'` is `True`.

Instead, try:

```py
a.loc[a.name=='bob', vars2change] = b.loc[:,vars2change].values
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Makes sense that the index was being used to align the dataframes and that changing to values converted the datatype of the right hand side so that alignment was ignored.